# Can't connect to mail on newly installed webserver

Tags: linux, email, postfix, dovecot

I just installed a new webserver running Debian Buster using the tutorial found here:

https://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-10-buster-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-1/

It replaced an old server also running Debian. The old server didn't have ISPConfig or Dovecot.

I copied all users from the old machine to the new machine (copied them from /etc/passwd and etc/shadow). That worked just fine. I can login on the new server through SSH using the original usernames and passwords.

The new server runs perfectly, except for one thing: email. Both the old and new server run Postfix. The new server apparently uses Dovecot for authentication. The old server got its mail users (and passwords) from the system password files (passwd and shadow). I have no clue where the new server gets its mail users from. But I can't get mail from the server using my original credentials. I use Thunderbird as my mail client and when I try to retrieve mail from the new server, Thunderbird displays the following pop-up:

```
Sending of password for user myname did not succeed. Mail server ---.---.---.--- responded: Authentication failed.
```

My /var/log/mail.info displays the following line:

```
Apr  2 02:12:20 enterprise dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (auth failed, 1 attempts in 6
secs): user=<myname>, method=PLAIN, rip=--.---.---.--, lip=---.---.---.---, session=
<k60mp0Oi9L1Z+KhX>
```

(ip adresses removed)

How can I get this working with the system passwd/shadow files again?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I needed to add the following to **/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf**:

```
passdb {
  driver = shadow
  args = blocking=no
}
userdb {
  driver = passwd
  args = blocking=no
}
```